# Zend PDO_MYSQL error in application.ini file

Tags: zend-framework, phpmyadmin, zend-db

When in configure my website which is working on zend to mysql in application.ini

```
resources.db.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
resources.db.isDefaultAdapter = true
resources.db.params.host = 67.227.236.194
resources.db.params.username = rdvscoin_rdvs
resources.db.params.password = P@ssw0rd
resources.db.params.dbname = rdvscoin_rdvs
```

after this when i run my page than Exception comes....
Message: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'rdvscoin_rdvs'@'host.indiandns.com' (using password: YES)
but above given information is correct.

Comment: I'm not being funny, but the error means that access is denied. Can you connect with those credentials via the MySQL command line utility?

Answer (score 0):

have you bootstrap the resource db?

```
    function _initRegDataBase(){
    $this->bootstrap('db');
    $ResourceDb = $this->getResource('db');
    $ResourceDb->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

Comment: There is exception is still is same .....Message: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'rdvscoin_rdvs'@'host.indiandns.com' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
resources.db.params.host = 67.227.236.194
```

with

```
resources.db.params.host = "host.indiandns.com"
```

Also remember this code will work on the server not on your computer because by default mysql remote access permission is denied . Secondly I think you are on share host which never gives IP address for free . So you got to use there name host instead.

Comment: Yeah this is my host name but there is error in username..but i provide a username which is i create by cpanel of share hosting.Message: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'rdvscoin_rdvs'@'host.indiandns.com' (using password: YES)